# What should I do with 'just bad posts' when reviewing for low quality posts

Tags: discussion, review-queues, low-quality-posts

Sometimes I meet an answer or a question which intention is clear, which is not link only answers or comment, but I personally think is not good answer (for example provides bad solution) or question. If I meet it while browsing Stackoverflow I could write a comment or downvote.

What exactly should I do if I meet such answer (or question) when reviewing for bad quality posts?